# init not being called on PDFPage subclass?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdf, inheritance, subclass

I have a custom `PDFDocument` class where I have subclassed `- (Class)pageClass` and return the `Class` method of my custom PDFPage.  Then in my PDFPage class I have created an implementation for `init` like so:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"Custom PDFClass initiated");
    }

return self;
}
```

and it is not being called when I open a PDF document.  I have checked the result of `- (PDFPage *)pageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index` and it is returning an instance of my custom class.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PDFPage** objects are usually created with [**initWithDocument**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzFramework/Classes/PDFPage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PDFPage/initWithDocument%3a) or [**initWithImage**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzFramework/Classes/PDFPage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PDFPage/initWithImage%3a), if you would like to do something at initialization, you should probably override both.

Comment: initWithDocument is listed as deprecated, I have tried overriding both of those as well and haven't had any luck